# Difference between storing data in stacks vs queues

Tags: java, stack, queue

What is the difference between the stack and the queue when it comes to data storage?

Comment: Depends on the implementation & features required. Might be identical, might not. Depends also on what exactly you mean by "data storage".

Comment: I just wanted to understand how the data is shifted around in each implementation. I'm learning data structures out of an old textbook that isn't really clear.

Comment: Well use a search engine. There are thousands of example implementations of either data structure out there. And there are many kinds of stacks and queues with sometimes very fancy features. Wikipedia has usually decent articles about the basic data structures too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack works like a tray of dirty dishes, the first one you put on the stack will be the last one out of the stack. The last one on the stack will be the first one popped off the stack (Last in first out).

The queue works in the same way a line at the supermarket works. The first one in a queue will be the first one out of the queue(First in first out).

Answer (score 1):

Stack - first in first out.

Queue - first in last out

Various methods to implement

Does that answer your homework

Comment: Stack is first in first out or not?

Comment: @user3600795 - What is the bit in the first statement do you not understand